# cache issue in rails application at production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

My Ruby on Rails application occasionally shows 404 errors to clients, but the issue resolves when they clear their browser cache. However, the server responds with a 200 status. The application is deployed on an EC2 instance with nginx and uses Ruby 2.7.2 and Rails 6.0.5. The nginx configuration looks like this:

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Connection '';
   proxy_pass http://puma;
}

location ^~ /var/www/app_name/assets/ {
   rewrite /var/www/app_name(/assets/.*) $1;
   root /var/www/app_name/public/;
   gzip_static on;
   expires max;
   add_header Cache-Control public;
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "";
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
```

The production cache configuration looks like this:

```rb
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = Rails.root.join("public", "cached_pages")
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{1.year.seconds.to_i}"
}
config.serve_static_files = true
config.cache_store = :redis_store, "#{ENV["REDIS_URL"]}/0", { expires_in: 180.minutes }
```

I'm using the gems `actionpack-page_caching` and `secure_headers`. Some clients experience this issue after leaving a system logged in for a day. The steps to reproduce the issue are:

1. i was enable development cache as like as production there is ssl true. first when i am trying to hit url then it return me ssl error on local, after update development.rb file with force_ssl = false
   for same browser it remain same error until i cleared the browser cache for other browser it looks good.
2. On another day, after logging in, some users encounter the 404 issue while the server receives the request just fine.
3. Sometimes the issue appears in one browser or system but not in another. Clearing the browser cache temporarily solves the problem.

Comment: Not enough information, most of the details in the initial question might be irrelevant. Nail it down to a particular query that gives the user 404 error, and drill down starting from that particular endpoint. It might or might not be caching-related - impossible to say based on the details provided.